# blending in Three-Dimensional

Tags: opengl

in my program the depth and blend are enabled so they will effect each other to get final result , there are two rectangle red and blue , the red is closer to view point .

when red is drawn first becomes opaque object and obscures the blue but when blue is drawn first , the red becomes translucent object and blends with the blue .

my interpretation is when red drawn first then the blue will not drawn because of depth buffer but in second state the blue will get a chance to be drawn and will be blended with red .

this interpretation Raises a question and this is my really question :

why does red become translucent when blue drawn first although it is closer to view point while in first state red is not translucent ?

enter code here

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


  void init(void)
   {
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClearDepth(1.0);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    }


 void v(void);

 void Red(void)
  {

glColor4f(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,-0.8);
glVertex3f(-0.5,0.5,-0.8);
glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.8);
glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,-0.8);
glEnd();

glFlush();

}

 void Blue(void)
  {


glColor4f(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,-0.7);
glVertex3f(-0.5,0.5,-0.7);
glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.7);
glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,-0.7);
glEnd();



glFlush();
}


 void Display(void)
{
v();

Red();
Blue(); 
}


void v()
 {
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {

 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowSize (200, 200);
 glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
 init();
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


 glutDisplayFunc(Display); 
 glutMainLoop();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> why does red become translucent when blue drawn first although it is closer to view point while in first state red is not translucent ?

Because depth testing and blending don't mix. Depth testing discards fragments (e.g. proto-pixels) just based on their depth value. If an incoming fragment fails the depth test, it gets discarded.

Blending however mindlessly just combines the color of pixels of the framebuffer with the incoming fragments. If the fragment gets discarded, nothing happens.

In effect this means, you can't retroactively blend things when they fail the depth test. Which means, that with blending you use the depth test only to get occluded by *opaque* geometry. But you don't perform depth writes and you have to sort everything far to near before drawing.

Comment: do you main that blue rectangle did not fail the depth test with red rectangle so it has been drawn and blended with red rectangle ?

Comment: @user1841718: That's exactly the case. But the red rectangle did fail the depth test, so nothing is drawn and you're left with the blending of the blue rectangle and whatever it was drawn over. OpenGL is not a scene graph, it has no concept of a world. All OpenGL knows about is drawing point, lines or triangles, one at a time to a canvas provided by the operating system. It's mostly smoke and mirrors, and depth testing is a cheap and easy way to implement hidden surface removal, at the price of not being able to do order independent transparency, which still is a topic of ongoing research.